# std sort seems to be looping forever

Tags: c++, sorting, std

Right now I have a class to do a binary search. The class accepts a vector, but then I tell the class to sort.

I need to be able to have it sort by only first name potentially or last name, so I set a character argument as a choice in that class to change how I sort the vector. I also in that class made an operator() function to use *this, as a class pointer to sort the vector. But it seems to just be looping forever. Can anyone tell me why? Code Below.

*note if there's some general practices I'm not following feel free to inform me. I don't want to start making bad habits now.

By request: Getname

```
void personType::getName(string& first, string& last)
{
    // get the name and set it
    first = firstName;
    last = lastName;
}


bool sBinary::operator()(studentType student1, studentType student2){
    string toCheck1, toCheck2, fName1,lName1 ,fName2 , lName2;
    student1.getName(fName1, lName1);
    student2.getName(fName2, lName2);
    toCheck1=checkStr(fName1, lName1);
    toCheck2=checkStr(fName2,lName2);
    return toCheck1<toCheck2;
}

string sBinary::checkStr(string fName, string lName){
    string toCheck;
    switch (choice){
    case 'f':
    case 'F':
        toCheck=fName;
        break;
    case 'l':
    case 'L':
        toCheck=lName;
        break;
    case 'r':
    case 'R':
        toCheck=fName+lName;
        break;
    default:
        toCheck=lName+fName;

    }

    return toCheck;

}


sBinary::sBinary(vector<studentType> _sList, char _choice){
    sList=_sList;
    steps=0;
    choice=_choice;
    sort(sList.begin(),sList.end(), *this);
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `break` in the `switch`. Regarding your question, I think we need to see `getName`.

Comment: It is seriously a badly written code.

Comment: `std::sort` has built-in checks to make sure the operator is not implemented in a invalid manner. I doubt the problem is in the operator.

Comment: Fixed break... Posted getName, ALso getName is not mine, i would just have a public function to get first name or last name. But its not my choice.

@Nawaz Yeah im a student, my code is probably pretty bad. But why dont you help me, be more specific. Just saying my code is bad doesnt help me at all.

Comment: You still need a `break` for the `'R'/'r'` case.

Comment: well, it doesn't loop forever http://ideone.com/XN5okx

Comment: sorry didnt update the stackoverflow post

Comment: Do you think my data has anything to do with it? I have about 2000 students, and they also have very similar names

Comment: If 2000 students cause it to hang, try 1000. We must distinguish between a process that runs *forever* and a process that runs *all day*.

Comment: Also if i take off the *this from sort, and just let the comparison operator work with the students, it sorts it, in no time at all.

Comment: @Beta got it down to 138 and its still looping. Also now that im looking at it, the call stack seems kinda strange. _sort calls _sort calls _sort, calls _Insertion_Sort calls Insertion_Sort calls Debug calls my function

Comment: Try 5. Or 2. Or 1. Or 0.

Comment: I got it down to 5 and it works

Comment: I guess i have to revamp my code to figure out how to have the same functionality outside of the search... but since the student stuff isnt my own, im not sure where to begin.... Id like to give you correct answer, so if somehow you want to make that happen i will.

Comment: Don't f'ck with a single comparator like this. if you want to sort by first name, last name or full name, write three comparators and use the one that matches `choice` at the time of *invoke*; not *during* the sort. Also, pass your objects in by const-reference, as making all those dupes cannot be healthy for your runtime =P

Comment: @WhozCraig You should write that up as an answer.  Stress the facts that 1) the choice should be made at the call site, and 2) copying the comparator should be cheap.  (There is, in fact, no reason why the comparator should contain _any_ data.)

Comment: @JamesKanze yeah I will. little chance of much up-votes but at least I could sleep a night =P

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, no it doesn't, not unless you turn on specific additional debugging code

Comment: @JamesKanze posted. took awhile (had to take the dogs for a walk =P) I sure hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, it seems not not to loop forever, but executes too long. It's completely different story.
You have a couple of pessimisations in your code:
The main concern is that you pass `*this`, to the sorting algorithm:

```
sort(sList.begin(),sList.end(), *this);
```

`std::sort` takes comparation predicate by value and it copies it many times. You can see it, if you define copy constructor:

```
sBinary(const sBinary& r):choice(r.choice), sList(r.sList)
{
    std::cout << "copied\n";
}
```

And your vector gets copied along with the object itself.

For example, if the array size is 200, `std::sort` copies object *13646 times*. It means, that *2700000* student copy operations involved.

So, you should not pass `*this` to `std::sort`. You'd better define static function `lessThen` instead of `operator()` and pass it to sorting algorithm.

### Further improvements:

1. [Pass by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/), rather then by value. For example, in your `lessThen` function declaration should look like

   ```
   static bool lessThen(const studentType& student1, const studentType& student2);
                      //^^^^^            ^
                      //constant         reference
   ```
2. Refactor your `studentType` class.

   You'd better have 2 separate functions, returning first and last name (by constant reference). In this case you could get rid of copying names to temporary variables. Note, that when you have single function, you have to copy both first and last name, even if one name will never be used:

   ```
   const std::string& first_name() const { return _fname; }
   const std::string& last_name() const { return _lname; }
   ```

Comment: So im looking on how to do this, but this kind of looks ugly... I know ive asked a lot already, but could you tell me if this code can be cleaned up at all? http://pastebin.com/EXUC7qYG

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with regards to using a static function.  I'd make the comparator a separate class.  (A member class, if need be, but definitely a separate class, with no data.)

Comment: @Ukemi, I don't think it is ugly. It is clear and efficient. One thing you can add is using _passage by reference_ instead of _passage  by value_. I'm playing with your code now, and replacing values with references scales productivity with a factor of 3.

Comment: Im not exactly sure what im supposed to be passing by reference.

Comment: @Ukemi, the function arguments. All of them!

Comment: @lol4t0 classes can make it easier to inline the comparison for some compilers, as the inlinability becomes local at the calling site.  Function pointers require analyzing all the way out of `sort`.  So it is an easy habit to get into.

Comment: @Ukemi, I've added some info

Comment: @Yakk, still, I don't believe it will be any particular difference in _this case_, except that function looks clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the extra... i would change the student class but its not mine to change. My instructor is pretty strict about not changing his code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm including this only because you should know alternatives to how you're sorting this list. Lol4t0 has already talked about the hideousness of having a comparator that is expensive to copy (and you would be hard pressed to have one more expensive than your original implementation).

The `std::sort` algorithms work best when given as simple a comparator as possible, with as much chance for inlining it's implementation as it can get. Ideally you implement a comparator operator function like this:

```
struct cmpObjects
{
    bool operator ()(const Object& left, const Object& right) const
    {
        return (left compared to right somehow);
    }
}
```

First notice the use of const references. The only time you should consider NOT doing this is if your underlying data is an native intrinsic type (such as `int`, `char`, etc.). In those cases it is actually *faster* to pass-by-value. But in this case, your student records are most-assuredly more efficient to access by reference (no copying).

Regarding your specific task, yours is a little more complicated based on the fact that you're sorting criteria is choice-based. If you want to maximize sort-speed you ideally have a single, tight, cheaply copyable comparator for each choice case. Then, use the proper comparator based on that choice, determined *before* invoking `std::sort`.

For example, if you know you're sorting on last name, then:

```
// compares last name
struct cmp_LName
{
    bool operator ()(const studentType& left, const studentType& right) const
    {
        return left.lastName < right.lastName;
    }
}
```

or perhaps first name, last name such as:

```
// compares first name, then last name only if first name is identical.
struct cmp_FNameLName
{
    bool operator ()(const studentType& left, const studentType& right) const
    {
        int res = left.firstName.compare(right.firstName);
        return res < 0 || (res == 0 && left.lastName < right.lastName);
    }
}
```

This makes a partial peek at your `sBinary` constructor now look like this:

```
sBinary(const std::vector<studentType>& sList_, char choice)
    : sList(sList_)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'L':
        case 'l':
            std::sort(sList.begin(), sList.end(), cmp_LName());
            break;

        case 'R':
        case 'r':
            std::sort(sList.begin(), sList.end(), cmp_FNameLName());
            break;

        ....
    }
}
```

Notice first we're making the choice for what comparison technique we're choosing *prior* to actually calling `std::sort`. When we do, we have the clear definition of what exactly that criteria is within the custom comparator we're using, and zero overhead it managing it.

So whats the trade off? You would need four comparators (cmp_LName, cmp_FName, cmp_FNameLName, and cmp_LNameFName), triggering which to use based on your incoming choice. However, the benefit for doing so cannot be overstated: *This will be the fastest way to sort your list based on choice.*

---

Addendum: **Single Comparator**

If you are absolutely positively married to the idea of using a single comparator, then make it as cheap to copy as possible, and bury the choice made in the sorting condition within it as `const` to give the compiler the best chance of cleaning up your code. I've included a full expansion of `sBinary` below to show how this can be done, but I stress, this is **not** optimal if speed is your primary concern.

```
class sBinary
{
    // compare student based on fixed choice determine at construction.
    struct cmp_student
    {
        const char choice;
        cmp_student(char choice) : choice(choice) {};

        bool operator()(const studentType& left, const studentType& right) const
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 'F':
                case 'f':
                    return left.firstName < right.firstName;

                case 'L':
                case 'l':
                    return left.lastName < right.lastName;

                case 'R':
                case 'r':
                {
                    int res = left.firstName.compare(right.firstName);
                    return res < 0 || (res == 0 &&  left.lastName < right.lastName);
                }

                default:
                {
                    int res = left.lastName.compare(right.lastName);
                    return res < 0 || (res == 0 &&  left.firstName < right.firstName);
                }
            }
        }
    };

public:
    sBinary(const std::vector<studentType>& sList, char choice)
        : sList(sList)
    {
        std::sort(sList.begin(), sList.end(), cmp_student(choice));
    }

    std::vector<studentType> sList;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive instructions. Im fine without the single comparator. As i said to Lol4t0 i would make these const but it cant be const and use getName() and i cant change getname as its my instructors code and hes really particular. I personally would have just made two get functions. 

Out of curiosity would the const be faster? I always thought const just keeps me from making mistakes and changing objects i shouldn't.

Comment: @Ukemi `const` does more than keep you from making modifications. It even more help to the compiler to generate super-tite optimized code. For most compilers today I'm not sure it would make a big difference (I know some people on here would know more about that, so perhaps they could chime in). But providing as much info as possible to the compiler about intent *at compile time* means less code analysis and better optimization in general. Especially when you tell the compiler from the outset "I'm never going to modify this thing." In your case,no `const`s, but still use references.

Comment: @Ukemi and were I you I would *rail* your instructor for providing a non-`const` "getter" interface. He/she should know better, and frankly should be teaching you said-same. It isn't too early to start such practices.